# How to contact directly Apple about Scams in iPad Apple Store?

Tags: ipad, apple-store

How can I contact Apple directly? At what times can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iPhone/iPad/etc. comes with 90 days telephone technical support.  The number you should use should be on the Applecare document for that device, I guess?

Comment: Also, I think this answer works [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65834/25260), direct contact. Anyway, good suggestion.